# Module is not disabling

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, error, mysql, cache

I am working on a client project and set up a development copy of the live site, front is working fine but admin is broken because of the fishpig wordpress integration actually i dont to set wordpress so didnt copy the db for this and want to disable the extension i disable the
by setting false in module config file under /app/etc/modules file and refresh the cache but the admin is not working log folder has wordpress.log file which is saying

`2013-05-01T19:14:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)`

also the cache is enabled looking for disable it from mysql and compilation is enabled too and admin is not opening :'(

Any body having any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename the directory

```
./app/code/community/Fishpig -> ./app/code/community/Fishpig.bak
```

That will disable it outright.

Disabling the module via the admin, or via `./app/etc/modules` doesn't always work if another class extends that class anyway.

---

You can disable the cache by removing the `./var/cache` directory (or by restarting Memcache/Redis/APC if you use them)

You can disable compiler by commenting out the `include $compilerConfig` line in `index.php`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer very informative but this didn't solved the error but as i see wordpress.log is not coming up in log folder anymore. May be some other issue is ditching me..

Comment: You asked how to disable a module and clear the cache. If you want to debug an issue, follow the debug guide here http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-debug-process/ - it will identify your issue.

Comment: Thx for debug stpe i have already tried some steps. front is good .. could my theme cause broken admin?

Comment: Follow every single step, to the letter. It WILL identify your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sonaasi disabling each module and activating one by one them had helped me finding the bug ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the cache via the command line using MageTool an addon for the Zend Framework command line application.

```
[ ~ ] $ zf | grep cache
zf clear mage-core-cache tags[=all]
zf flush mage-core-cache
zf enable mage-core-cache tags[=all]
zf disable mage-core-cache tags[=all]
```

To disable the cache on your site use the following command inside the directory that contains your magento app folder (Magento Root Directory)

```
zf disable mage-core-cache tags=all
```

To install the zf cli and the magetool, visit https://github.com/alistairstead/MageTool for more instructions

Comment: Thanks for this tool actually i disabled the cache from DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you use disk-based caching you can clear the `var/cache/` directory from your Magento root.